# command to press a key after delay ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, firefox-extensions, xubuntu

I'm trying to make firefox automatically fullscreen on startup. I've tried a couple extensions that all crash firefox. Firefox also automatically starts on system startup.

I think the easiest solution at the moment would be to execute a command that runs at startup that presses F11 after a delay (30 seconds?) to allow for firefox to startup fully.

What command could I run to do this?

Thanks,
Blaine

Answer (score 1):

You can try [xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/) to send F11 to Firefox:

```csh
# adapted from http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/#idp24160 
sleep 30
WID=`xdotool search "Mozilla Firefox" | head -1`
xdotool windowactivate --sync $WID
xdotool key --clearmodifiers F11
```